# All styling (and other usual page scaffolding) missing on the page shown for question-blocked users

Tags: support, bug, asking-questions

If you are blocked from asking questions, you go to this own sub-site on Stack Overflow main site (not meta). For some reason, this site is just white with text. Like all the HTML and CSS files are invalid. What is up with that?

When I press "ask question" on Stack Overflow, the screen appears like this:

[image]

It has been like this for about 1 month.

Before it was not like that. It looked more like this:

[image]

This is not a duplicate, because it is a problem in the code of the site(I think). I can access all sites fine, and it is not a connection problem.

Comment: It isnt. It has been like that for about 1 month. If it was an issue about sites down, it would have been fixed earlier

Comment: Can you open the Network tab of the developer tools as see if there are any errors? Ditto with the Console? There may be clues there...

Comment: Maybe the recent CSS changes broke it. This is an area of the site most people don't see, and probably most people that do see it aren't interested in reporting such things.

Comment: It is just an approximate estimation from my side, that was when I noticed it but at that point I hadn't been on SO in about 3 months. It could be longer, but that is how long I have seen it.